# "Git gc" complains about a bad object, but "git fsck" does not. How can I find what references this bad object?

Tags: git

When I run `git gc`, I get the following output:

```
error: Could not read bf493234ee6eb0ca12573136510e35d12f1adc51
Counting objects: 885373, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (150591/150591), done.
Writing objects: 100% (885373/885373), done.
Total 885373 (delta 480155), reused 885373 (delta 480155)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
error: Could not read bf493234ee6eb0ca12573136510e35d12f1adc51
Checking connectivity: 908348, done.
```

However, running `git fsck` only turns up a number of dangling objects, with no corruption detected. Similarly, a `grep -r "bf49" ~/git/.git/logs` turns up nothing.

How can I track down what is referencing this non-existent object, and why isn't `git fsck` finding it?

Answer (score -1):

Before the `git fsck` execute `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`.

This will clear out all the dangling data. after it complete run `fsck` again.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question. I'm not having an issue with the dangling data. I'm getting an error message while running "git gc", and I want to find out what's causing it.